# Airflow - Run DAG three different times a day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Apache Airflow. In Airflow I can add cron like syntax but is there any way to run a DAG three different times a day?

From cron syntax I can only add if the time is in a certain interval. But I want to run job three completely different time.

For example I want to run a job **3.50 PM**, **7.15 PM** and **11.59 PM** everyday.

Comment: If you change the minutes to be all the same, you can easily do that through cron expression. ([maybe something like that](https://crontab.guru/#50_15,19,23_*_*_*) )

Answer (score 1):

The solution I think is creating 3 separate dags with [dagrun operator](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/dagrun_operator.html) and schedule those dags at time 3.50 PM, 7.15 PM and 11.59 PM.

Within each dag, you can trigger your main dag using dag-run operator.

Comment: An improvement to above answer would be by using a Short Circuit Operator https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.ShortCircuitOperator . This operator allows a workflow to continue only if a condition is met. Otherwise, the workflow “short-circuits” and downstream tasks are skipped.

Comment: Really? That's pretty ridiculous :/ `start_date` is a silly thing, what if we want this level of resolution to be on hours...